# JavaFX - MVC - How can I load images from another package

Tags: java, javafx-2, executable-jar

I have a problem which appears when I export to runnable jar.

Basically I am creating a JavaFx Game which loads Images by using:

Image image = new Image(BlueCar.class.getResource("../resources/blueCar.png").toExternalForm());

Everything works fine within eclipse. However when I try to export and run it give a error on the line of code above.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD7jc.jpg

I am using MVC Pattern for the application so I have packages separating the class from the images resources:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQqLy.jpg

Please if you could help know what I am doing wrong please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jar filesystem does not support relative paths - use absolute ones getClass().getClassloader().getResource("path/to/resource/blueCar.jpg")

Comment: It gives me a error when I try to use the full path in this case is:

C:\Users\blid\Desktop\Aldo\SWA\Game Project SWA\Assignment1\src\assignment1\resources\0.png

right?

Comment: The path is not the absolute filesystem path but absolute in regard of the classloader - so eg if the files are in a package a.b.c the path is a/b/c/myfile.png

Comment: In your sample it is assignment1/resources/0.png